# how to turn off execution ms / step in colab

Tags: output, google-colaboratory

out of a sudden I get in my output cell of my colab's notebook the execution time for each step: has anybody an idea how this can be turned off?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2B1G.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, just found out that it has nothing to do with colab. The info came from keras and I had to choose the verbose parameter 0